# Extract strings from pandas df using regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I need help with regex for Python Pandas dataframe.
Testing strings would be:

```
s = pd.Series(['xslF345X03/was-form4_163347386959085.xml', 'xslF345X03/wf-form4_163347386959085.xmlasdf', 'xslF345/X03/wf-form4_163347386959085.xml'])
```

I would like to:

- **extract starting from the last '/' till the '.xml' at the end**
- **extract only when the string ends with '.xml'**

so that I get something like this:

```
xslF345X03/was-form4_163347386959085.xml      Extract: /was-form4_163347386959085.xml
xslF345X03/wf-form4_163347386959085.xmlasdf   Do not extract because the ending is not .xml
xslF345/X03/wf-form4_163347386959085.xml      Extract starting from the last '/' character: /wf-form4_163347386959085.xml
```

I figured I need following pandas code to extract using regex:

```
s.str.extract(...)
```

Thank you in advance :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract starting from the last '/' character **(including the `/`)** till end of `.xml`, use `str.extract()`, as follows:

```
s.str.extract(r'(/(?!.*/).*\.xml)$')
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/PlqCp8/1)

**Regex Details:**

`(`    -   Start of capturing group for `str.extract()`

`/`  - match symbol / literally

`(?!.*/)`   - Negative lookahead regex to assert no further symbol / after it (i.e. **to ensure the symbol / is the last one**)

`.*`   - match zero or more characters

`\.`   - match a dot literally (escape to avoid confusion with regex meta-character)

`xml`  - match string `xml` literally

`)`   - End of capturing group for `str.extract()`

`$`  - assert at end of line (to ensure the `.xml` is at the end)

**Result:**

```
                                0
0  /was-form4_163347386959085.xml
1                             NaN
2   /wf-form4_163347386959085.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `str.extract`:

```
>>> s.str.extract(r'.*/(.*\.xml)$')
                               0
0  was-form4_163347386959085.xml
1                            NaN
2   wf-form4_163347386959085.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check with `str.endswith` then pass to the `np.where`

```
np.where(s.str.endswith('.xml'),s.str.rsplit('/',n=1).str[-1],np.nan)
Out[99]: 
array(['was-form4_163347386959085.xml', nan,
       'wf-form4_163347386959085.xml'], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Hello BENY, thanks for your answer. I know your solution works, I prevented that, because of performance concern. Therefore I would like it to be done in one operation using "extract" and regex. Do you think the performance of your solution differs a lot or just minimal than "extract"+regex?